# Count number of $m$ elements set from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose sum is multiple of $m$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to count number of $m$ elements set from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose sum is multiple of $m$.

That's number of set $\{x_1, x_2,\cdots,x_m\}$ with $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m \equiv 0 \pmod m$.
By using a computer, I found that it seems the result is

$$\frac1m\sum_{d|m} (-1)^{m-d} \varphi(\frac md){\lfloor\frac{dn}m\rfloor\choose d }$$

but I could not prove it. Could anyone help to prove it or provide a counterexample?

Comment: I did not check your result but you can write the $q-$binomial as $q^{\binom{m}{2}}{n\brack m}_q=\sum _{|X|=m}q^{\sigma (X)}$ where $\sigma (X)$ is the sum of the elements of $X$ and you want exactly the ones that are divisible by $m$. I would try to evaluate the $q-$binomial on a primitive $m-$root of unity to see what happens. Perhaps the generating function of $\varphi$ appears somehow.

Comment: Continue to look up the count of equation $x_1+x_2+...+x_m \equiv h (mod m)$, it seems the result is $\frac1m \sum_{d|m} (-1)^{m-d} \varphi(\frac md)g(\frac m{dh}) {\lfloor\frac{dn}m\rfloor \choose d}$ where $g(p^a)=\begin{cases}0&a\ge 2\\\frac1{1-p}&a=1\\1&a\le 0\end{cases}$. And  $g(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_t^{a_t})=g(p_1^{a_1})\cdots g(p_t^{a_t})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phicar's suggestion in the comments is a good one. It follows from the [q-binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem) that
$$q^\binom{m}{2} \binom{n}{m}_q = \sum_{X \subset [n] : |X| = m} q^{\sigma(X)}, \qquad (*)$$
where $\sigma(X)$ is the sum of the elements of a subset $X \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$. We are going to evaluate this expression on all complex $m$th roots of unity and sum. On the right-hand side, the only terms which survive are those with $\sigma(X) \equiv 0 \pmod m$, so we get precisely $m$ times what we want. What do we get on the left-hand side?

Say $q = e^{i2\pi k / m}$. First, $q^\binom{m}{2} = e^{i2\pi k (m-1)/2} = (-1)^{k(m-1)}$. Second, by definition
$$ \binom{n}{m}_q = \frac{(q^n - 1)(q^{n-1} - 1) \cdots (q^{n-m+1} - 1)}{(q^m-1) (q^{m-1} - 1) \cdots (q - 1)}.$$
The apparent singularities near roots of unity are all removable (this follows from (*) for example). We can evaluate $\binom{n}{m}_q$ when $q$ is a primitive $d$th root of unity, where $d \mid m$, by applying l'Hospital's rule $m/d$ times. Let $n'$ be the largest multiple of $d$ less than $n$. Then we get
$$ \frac{n'(n'-d) \dots (n'-m+d)}{m(m-d) \dots d} = \binom{n'/d}{m/d}.$$
Since there are $\varphi(d)$ primitive $d$th roots of unity, all together we get
$$\sum_{d \mid m} (-1)^{m(m-1)/d} \varphi(d) \binom{n'/d}{m/d}.$$
This is equivalent to your expression. (Regarding the sign factor, if $m$ is even then the sign factor is $(-1)^{m/d}$, so we agree in this case, while if $m$ is odd then the sign factor is always 1 and so is yours, so we agree in that case too.)

Comment: BTW, how did you find this expression "using a computer"?

Comment: First define $C_m(u,n,h)$ as number of u elements set from [n] whose sum is h modular m. 
Classify set above according to whether the set contains number n, we have
$C_m(u,n,h)=C_m(u,n-1,h)+C_m(u-1,n-1,h-n)$
Classify set above according to whether the set contains number 1 and subtract all elements by 1, we have
$C_m(u,n,h)=C_m(u,n-1,h-u)+C_m(u-1,n-1,h-u)$

Comment: After that we could compute $C_m(m,n,0)$ via pari/gp code:

getC(N,m)={
   local(C,D,v,R);
   C=matrix(N,m);
   D=matrix(N,m);
   R=vector(N);
   for(h=1,m,
     for(n=1,N,
       C[n,h]=floor(n/m);
       if(h<=n%m, C[n,h]=C[n,h]+1)
     )
   );
   for(u=2, m,
      for(n=1, u-1,
         for(h=1,m,D[n,h]=0)
      );
      for(n=u,N,
         for(h=1,m,
             v=h-u;if(v<=0,v+=m);
             D[n,h]=D[n-1,v]+C[n-1,v]
         )
      );
      C=D
   );
   for(n=1,N,
      R[n]=C[n, m]
   );
   R
}

Comment: Next we could focus on n=km+r and it is easy to determine that $C_m(m,km+r,u)$ are order-m polynomial of k and we could find the polynomial:
getPolys(m)={
   local(C, P, H, R, r);
   C=getC(m*(m+1),m);
   H=matrix(m+1,m+1);
   for(u=1,m+1,
      H[u,1]=1;
      for(v=1,m, H[u,v+1]=(u-1)^v)
   );
   R=matrix(m+1,m);
   for(u=1,m+1,
      for(v=1,m,
         R[u,v]=C[(u-1)*m+v]
      )
   );
   R=H^-1*R;
   P=vector(m);
   for(u=1,m,
      P[u]=R[m+1,u];
      for(v=1,m,
         if(u==m, P[u]*=k-1,P[u]*=k);
         P[u]+=R[m+1-v,u]
      )
   );
   P
}

Comment: Subtract polynomial above by $\frac{n\choose m}{m}$ and I found the order of polynomial left is largest factor of m and coefficient of it is $\frac{u^{u-1}}{u!}\frac{d-1}d$ where m=ud.

Comment: In the other hand, since $C_m(m,n,h)=C_m(m,n-1,h)+C_m(m-1,n-1,h-n)$ and $C_m(m,n,h)=C_m(m,n-1,h)+C_m(m-1,n-1,h)$, we have $C_m(m-1,n-1,h)=C_m(m-1,n-1,h-n)$, which means $C_m(m-1,n-1,h) = C_m(m-1,n-1,h-\lambda gcd(m,n))$
esp. $C_m(m,n,h)=c_m(m,n-1,h)+\frac{n-1\choose m-1}{m}$ if $n\neq 0(\mod m)$
which hints that the result is related to factor of m and finally I found the formula.

Comment: formula should be $C_m(u,n,h)=C_m(u-1,n−1,h)+C_m(u−1,n−1,h−n)$ and $C_m(u,n,h)=C_m(u-1,n−1,h−u)+C_m(u−1,n−1,h−u) $

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Comment: I could get your idea now.
For ${n \choose m}_q$ where q is primitive d-th root of unity, we could find the result is $\lim_{q\to\omega_d}\frac{(q^{n'd}-1)(q^{(n'-1)d}-1)\cdots (q^{(n'-r+1)d)}-1)}{(q^d-1)(q^{2d}-1)\cdots (q^{r d}-1)}$  since all non-zero factors could be eliminated, where rd=m and $\omega_d$ is primitive d-th root of unity.
For $\lim_{q\to\omega_d} \frac{q^{(n'-h+1)d}-1}{q^{hd}-1}$, L'Hospital's rule could be applied to result in $\frac{n'-h+1}h$

Comment: Nice, +1, the L'hopital can be avoided using $q-$Lucas.